# Function gets called twice for each click

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

The `$(".actionsAdListnTo").click`  function is getting fired twice.
I tried various solutions posted in StackOverflow but nothing worked.

What is the reason of twice firing any pointers please.

How to avoid this?

```
$(".actionsAdListnTo").click(function (e) {
    $('#actionsAdListnTo').slideToggle();
});

$(".ddlAddListinTo li").click(function () {
    var urlstring = "../ActionTypes";
    var ddlselectedVal = $(this).attr('id');
    var $form = $("#frmPostToEmailReports");
    var selectedListinsCount = selected_Listings.length;
    var SelectedMlsnums = selected_Listings.join();

    if (ddlselectedVal != "None" && ddlselectedVal != "select") {

        //***********  To Cart Functionality
        if (ddlselectedVal == 'Tocart') {
            if (selectedListinsCount > 500) {
                if ($('#errmesg').length == 0) {
                    $('.messageCenter').append('<span id="errmesg" class ="errmesg"> <span class="messageIcon"></span><span>The maximum number of listings you may select To Add to cart is 500.</span></span>');
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                $.post(urlstring,

                function (data) {
                    $(window.open(urlstring, '_blank', 'width=750, height=400')).load(function (e) {
                        var $formCopy = $("#frmPostToEmailReports").clone();
                        $($formCopy).append('<input id="SelectedMlsnums" name="SelectedMlsnums" type="hidden" value="' + SelectedMlsnums + '">');
                        // Here "this" will be the popup window. insert a form element into the popup window.
                        $(this.document).find("#divfrmInfo").html($formCopy);
                        e.preventDefault();
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

HTML :

```
<div class="actionsAdListnTo">
     <span> <a href="#" id="select" class="ClearData">Add Listing To</a></span>
     <ul id="actionsAdListnTo" class="ddlAddListinTo" style="display: block;">
            <li id="Tocart">To CART</li>
            <li id="Toportal">To Portal</li>
            <li id="SaveListings">Save Listing</li>                                       
      </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Because of event bubbling you are facing this issue.

Comment: In addition, In this specific scenario I see it more correct to attach the toggle event to the `a` directly instead of the outer `div`. Not only does it solve the event bubbling but it also makes your code more specific with intent. Do you want the `div` to toggle the list or the link? Further more, if you add more elements with events to the `div` you don't need to continuously worry about event bubbling and add `stopPropagation` all over the place just for the sake of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it looks it would be more correct to target the link only for the toggle and not the outer `div`. Be as specific with your selectors as possibe, similar to this:

```
$(".actionsAdListnTo a#select").click(function (e) {    
    $('#actionsAdListnTo').slideToggle();
});
```

If you want to be more specific without an id using the structure, you could do it simlar to:

```
$(".actionsAdListnTo > span:first > a").click(function (e) { 
    $('#actionsAdListnTo').slideToggle();
});
```

Anyway, the way your HTML is structured there is no need to have the toggle triggered by the `div` as only the link should react to it.

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/BQV7d/) - Getting more specific with the selector

---

Answer (score 3):

The click on `li` bubbles to its parents, one of them being `<div class="actionsAdListnTo">`, so the parent's click handler is also called. Try to stop propagation of the click on `li`:

```
$(".ddlAddListinTo li").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

What I see here is that you are defining two events in the same place, the second one on a child.

```
$(".actionsAdListnTo").click( function(e){
  ...
});
$(".ddlAddListinTo li").click(function () {
  ...
})
```

Maybe you can use e.sTopPropagation() in the second one, or e.preventDefault()